# FHIR Coverage resource

Tags: json, sample, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I am working an a project to create FHIR Coverage resource for Patient ID search.

I am looking for examples of Coverage resource especially for medicare insurance. I tried a lot but could not find examples for Medicare.

Can someone please share some samples or provide any pointers.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to use the Da Vinci PDex patient match operation?

Comment: No. Our requirement is to use Consumer-Directed Payer Data Exchange
https://build.fhir.org/ig/HL7/carin-bb/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question. Are on the official FHIR chat on Zulip (chat.fhir.org)? We have a CARIN Consumer Directed Payer Data Exchange (aka CARIN Blue Button) IG stream there (https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/204607-CARIN-Blue.20Button.20IG) where this and similar questions are addressed.

As far as your question, for Coverage resource details regarding traditional Medicare insurance, currently you'd want to browse the STU3-based CMS Blue Button API 2.0 documentation at https://bluebutton.cms.gov/developers/#core-resources. I say "currently" because it is possible that at some point in time that API will move to the R4-based CARIN BB IG. Do note that the CMS Blue Button 2.0 API is the inspiration behind the CARIN BB IG.

Hope this helps.
-Amol Vyas (https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/pm-with/192132-tech)

Comment: Thank you Amol. !! I did join the FHIR Chat on Zulip and got some details from the discussions. Also I do have access to bluebutton developer sandbox and referred to some medicare samples. But those sample are not in alignment with the latest FHIR standards for Coverage resource and was not much helpful.

Comment: Understood. My only other suggestion for getting your CMS Medicare BB 2.0 API concerns addressed would be to get on the Google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/Developer-group-for-cms-blue-button-api). I do know that the CMS BB API team frequently monitors and addresses questions there. Good luck!